# Python 3: best way to implement your own type with constraints

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, user-defined-types

I'm doing a Python 3 based data conversion and certain character based fields I operate on have specific character allowances and length constraints applied to them.

I'd want to have some sort of swappable/configurable constraint function I roll myself that I could call.

1. Can you extend str?
2. Is it best to define a class for this and make variables implementations of that class.

Or are there simpler ways to do this with Python 3?

I'm wondering if anyone can give me pointers as to what to Google for inspiration?

(My initial thoughts are to look at SQLAlchemy's internal code for inspiration for things like Column).
EDIT: SQLAlchemy's code is too sophisticated for this scenario!

---

For example a type that only allows:

- alphanumerics (upper+lowercase)
- numerics
- plus a selection of special characters.
  This may vary by field, but some may use same function.
  Hence desire to create custom re-usable types.
- I'll do character stripping or substitution.

Then one may only allow 50 chars, whilst another may allow 500 etc.

I'll pass back a tuple with original value, converted value, a boolean to indicate truncation occurred

Comment: Please show some actual data and some attempts you've made. Right now this is way too broad and somewhat unclear as well.

Comment: WRT "Can you extend str?", try it. The beauty of Python is that the attempt should take up almost as little space as the question.

Comment: What does "variables implementations of that class" mean?

Comment: @MadPhysicist meaning I say field1 = TypeX(constraint=constrainfun, maxlen=100) to create instance of type.. The constraintfun would get called in the set method. A template method pattern

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Also I'm not sure if that's best approach (extending str), since that has far more functionality and has methods I don't necessarily need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

**valobj.py**

```
import utils
class UDT:

    def __init__(self, converter, maxlen, value):
        if utils.getClassName(converter) != 'function':
            raise TypeError(f'converter {converter} is not a function')
        if int(maxlen) <= 0:
            raise TypeError(f'maxlen {maxlen} must be 1 or more')
        if utils.getClassName(value) != 'str':
            raise TypeError(f'value {value} is not a Python String')
        self.converter = converter
        self.maxlen = int(maxlen)
        self.value = value

    def convert(self):
        intermed = self.converter(self.value)
        truncated = len(intermed) > self.maxlen
        result = intermed[:self.maxlen] if truncated else intermed
        return (result, truncated, self.value)

class Job:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name_tuple = UDT(utils.fix_chars, 64, name).convert()
```

**utils.py**

```
import string
def getClassName(arg):
    return(str(type(arg)).replace("<class '","").replace("'>",""))

def fix_chars(text) -> str:
    result = ''
    for c in text:
        if ( (string.ascii_letters.find(c) != -1)
        or   (string.digits.find(c) != -1)
        or   ('._-#'.find(c) != -1)
           ):
            result += c
        else:
            result += '_'
    result = tidy_up_str(result)
    return (result)

def tidy_up_str(text) -> str:
    result = text
    result = result.replace('_-_', '_')
    while result.find('__') != -1:
        result = result.replace('__', '_')
    if result.endswith('_'):
        result = result[:-1]
    return result
```